# Seek to understand the Scrapy Callback

Tags: python, mysql, callback, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to grasp the concept of Scrapy Callback. I had not been able to find any answers that sutied my issue as i needed to yield items twice in both pars an yet be able to callback.

This is my spider:

```
import scrapy
import csv

from scrapycrawler.items import DmozItem
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.lxmlhtml import LxmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import Request


class DmozSpider(CrawlSpider):
   name = "dmoz"
   allowed_domains = ["snipplr.com"]


def start_requests(self):
    #for i in xrange(1000):
    for i in range(1, 1000):
        yield self.make_requests_from_url("http://www.snipplr.com/all/page/%d" % i)

def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//ol[@class="snippets marg"]/li[1]/h3'):
        item = DmozItem()
        item['title'] = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()
        item['link'] = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()
        return Request(item['link'],  request.meta={'item':item}, callback=self.parse2)
        yield item

def parse2(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//div[@class="description"]'):
        item = response.meta["item"]            
        item['desc'] = sel.xpath('p/text()').extract()
        yield item
```

This is my pipeline:

```
import csv
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy import log
import sys
import mysql.connector

class CsvWriterPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', user='sq', passwd='rt', db='sq')
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.cursor.execute("SELECT title,url FROM items WHERE title= %s", item['title'])
        result = self.cursor.fetchone()
        if result:

            log.msg("Item already in database: %s" % item, level=log.DEBUG)
        else:
            self.cursor.execute(
               "INSERT INTO items (title, url) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
                    (item['title'][0], item['link'], item['desc'][0]))
            self.connection.commit()

            log.msg("Item stored : " % item, level=log.DEBUG)
        return item

    def handle_error(self, e):
            log.err(e)

i am basically trying to get the data both from the first page and the page there after the page has been crawled. I am using Scrapy webcrawler an mysql.
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to `yield` a `Request`, not `return`:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//ol[@class="snippets marg"]/li[1]/h3'):
        item = DmozItem()
        item['title'] = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()
        item['link'] = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()
        yield Request(item['link'],  request.meta={'item':item}, callback=self.parse2)
        yield item
```

Comment: Ok, Did that and had a Key Error though, items was present and so was pipeline.

Comment: Ok, Did that and had a Key Error though, items was present and so was pipeline.

This is the code for both spider and pipeline respectively: http://hastebin.com/doyexejazu.py

The error:
   return self._values[key]
        exceptions.KeyError: 'descs'

Comment: This is Items class if needed for reference, Thanks.


import scrapy

`class DmozItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    descs = scrapy.Field()`

Comment: @CharlieC I think you don't need to yield an item from the `parse()` callback.

Comment: @Alex e but that would disallow me to retrieve items from the first phase wouldint it ?

Comment: @CharlieC if you really need it, then  you should set `item['desc']` - otherwise it would fail in the pipeline. Set it to `None`, for example: `item['desc'] = None`.

Comment: Hmm, wouldnt that also bring up the issue on how i would handle item['descs'] in the pipeline later?, the 2nd phase. Cant possible do what i am doing in the pipeline atm due to it needing a attribute to work.

Comment: @CharlieC well, at least this would help with the `KeyError`. I'm not sure how you were planning to work with items that have missing `desc` key.

Comment: Scrap items > get href on first page(parse 1) > callback to parse 2 > parse 2 scrapes the/every href page retrieved from parse 1. Hope this would be a better representation of what is trying to be achieved here. Thanks :)